# Best pattern for GraphQL create or update form with React?

Tags: reactjs, state, apollo, react-apollo

I am new to GraphQL but have experience in React.

I am trying to build a simple app with React and Apollo where the same form is used to create or update an entity, say a *Post*.

I don't want to duplicate the form, so i thought i would define a `PostForm` component and use from both `CreatePostPage` and `UpdatePostPage` pages.

**CreatePostPage.js (simplified)**

```
const CreatePostPage = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Create Post</h1>
    <Mutation mutation={POST_CREATE}>
      {(createPost, {data}) => (
        <PostForm onSubmit={(formData) => createPost(formData)} />
      )}
    </Mutation>
  </div>
)
```

**UpdatePostPage.js (simplified)**

```
const UpdatePostPage = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Update Post</h1>
    <Query query={POST_GET} variables={{id: match.params.id}}>
      {({ data, networkStatus }) => {
        const post = data && data.post ? omitDeep(data.post, '__typename') : null;
        return (
          <Mutation mutation={POST_UPDATE}>
            {(updatePost, {data}) => (
              <PostForm post={post} onSubmit={(formData) => updatePost(formData)} />
            ))}
          </Mutation>
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  </div>
  )
```

Now `PostForm` needs to maintain its own state so that the user can edit the post.
I was planning to use `componentWillReceiveProps()`, saw that the way to do this now would be `getDerivedStateFromProps()`, then read multiple time that i [Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)...

So i am wondering if this is the right way to do this?

My issue is well described in this [medium article](https://medium.com/@ddunderfelt/controlled-forms-with-react-f7ecc1ce6155)
and i implemented the solution (which is also proposed by React team)

But it feels quite hacky.
Is this the right way to do this or should i handle the local state differently? Wondering how Dan Abramov would handle a simple create/update app like this =)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: i am also facing state issue in update form . Would you please send me demo code link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a stateful component for your `PostForm`, but as far as I can tell there's no need for you to utilize either `componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. In this particular case, your `post` prop is just there to initialize your state. What you should do is prevent your component from rendering until you actually have the post data.

You could just do something like this:

```
<Query query={POST_GET} variables={{id: match.params.id}}>
  {({ data, networkStatus }) => {
    if (!data.post) return null; // data itself should never be undefined
    const post = omitDeep(data.post, '__typename');
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={POST_UPDATE}>
        {(updatePost, {data}) => (
          <PostForm post={post} onSubmit={(formData) => updatePost(formData)} />
        ))}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

Then inside your PostForm's constructor, you can set your initial state to whatever the value of `props.post`.

Of course, you may want to account for loading and error states, in which case you should render the appropriate components instead depending on the values provided by the `Query` component.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Daniel! I think i need `getDerivedStateFromProps` because  PostForm state also needs to be updated when the mutation returns the mutated post from the API (when the form is submitted)? This is what the medium article describes. Anyway i was mostly afraid of using a stateful component for this, you're reassuring me..

Comment: @skiplecariboo Even though the mutation data is returned as part of the render props function's signature, I believe calling `mutate` should return a Promise that resolves to the mutation's result. That means inside your form, you can await the mutate call and then use the result data to `setState`.